# indicating strings in javascript without quotation marks

Tags: javascript, string

I came across a bit of code that looks something like this:

```
var str="I like blue";
str.replace(/blue/,"red");
```

What is happening here? When are string literals not required to be enclosed in quotes? What is the benefit of this approach as opposed to

```
str.replace("blue","red");
```

Comment: When it's a regular expression. [You can see from the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) that `String.replace` can take a regex as the first argument.

Comment: The expression `/blue/` is a [regular expression literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Comment: `/blue/` is not a string literal, it's a regular expression literal.  `.replace` can search for either a string or a regex.

Comment: *"When are string literals not required to be enclosed in quotes?"* Never. *"What is the benefit of this approach as opposed to"* There is none in your example, but see http://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/218196

Comment: replace can do more things with regular expressions, you can replace patterns and also do global replaces, eg <code>"abcbabcba".replace(/b/g,"_") // == "a_c_a_c_a"</code>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When are string literals not required to be enclosed in quotes?

[Never](https://es5.github.io/#x7.8.4):

```
StringLiteral ::
    " DoubleStringCharacters_opt "
    ' SingleStringCharacters_opt '
```

(Note: [*template literals*](https://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-template-literal-lexical-components) in ES6 are not string literals either.)

> What is the benefit of this approach as opposed to [...]

There is none in your example, but if you want to replace all occurrences of a string, you have to use a [regular](https://es5.github.io/#x7.8.5) [expression](https://es5.github.io/#x7.8.5) with the global modifier: [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1144783/218196)

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript, a literal enclosed within `/` characters is not a String, is a [RegExp (regular expression)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

So `/blue/` is equivalent to `new RegExp("blue")`